# using two canvases as two layers

Tags: android, android-canvas

is it possible to use two canvases in the same view, so it will be like to layers?
because i want to delete something and somthing else to remain, so i thought of putting each thing in each canvas.

and if it is possible, how do i do that while using surfaceHolder?
i lock the holder on one canvas, draw on it and the unlock and post ,and then do the same for the other canvas? like this?

```
canvas1=this.getHolder().lockCanvas();
this.onDraw(canvas1);
this.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas1);

canvas2=this.getHolder().lockCanvas();
this.onDraw(canvas2);
this.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas2);
```

Tnx for the help :D

Comment: no, there is only one Canvas

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: why do you need something like multilayer Canvad?

Comment: i amking an object that moves and a backround, and i dont want to redraw the backround allover again every loop when the object moves

Comment: you have to draw everything when using SurfaceView: "The content of the Surface is never preserved between unlockCanvas() and lockCanvas(), for this reason, every pixel within the Surface area must be written."

Comment: alright gotit Tnx pskink, i'll do it in another way